# adding custom interactive js in wix studio

Tags: javascript, velo

hello i want  to know how can i add

```
<script src="three.r134.min.js"></script>
<script src="vanta.birds.min.js"></script>
<script>
VANTA.BIRDS({
  el: "#your-element-selector",
  mouseControls: true,
  touchControls: true,
  gyroControls: false,
  minHeight: 200.00,
  minWidth: 200.00,
  scale: 1.00,
  scaleMobile: 1.00,
  backgroundColor: 0x#2f2e2e,
  wingSpan: 40.00,
  separation: 30.00,
  alignment: 43.00,
  cohesion: 19.00
})
</script>
```

this in my wix website on the homepage background, in a container

i tried using the site custom code but i cant add and tried to find other blogs nothing is there